# How to start run in eclipse by command line?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there anyway that I can start the run in eclipse by command line to run the java code in locate project, just like using the run button of eclipse.
How to set up the run command and appoint the eclipse and the java project.

Comment: Do you use Maven in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the code in eclipse to an executable .jar file and run it on console. To execute the .jar file in for Example the cmd, you need the path of the package. An example could be: `java -Xmx1024m -jar /path/to/the/jar.jar`.

Comment: Thanks, but i want the programme runns in eclipse, seems like it was started using the run button of eclipse